# Docker containers memory consumption

Tags: docker, memory

I'm working on project where I divided the application in multiple docker images and I'm running around 5 containers where each one has its own image. Following the "One process per container" rule.

For that I'm using a beaglebone black which has only 480Mb of memory. Sometimes when the application runs for some time it crashes due to Out of memory exception.

So I was wondering if I make the images smaller would it consume less memory? How is the memory allocated for each container?

What if I group some images/containers into a single running container with more than one process? Would it use less memory?

Comment: I don't know enough about Docker, but hearing your application runs for some time then crashes due to some out of memory exception, I can't help but think that the container leaks memory, either originating at the application, or some other component. Adding memory to the container won't fix your problem -- just prolong the inevitable crash. Then again, you should probably assess what amount of memory the application should need as maximum, assuming it doesn't leak any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a process is killed with an OOM exception this is not related to the docker image size, this is the amount of memory the process is trying to use.

You can specify some memory limits on each container when you run them.

For example this will limit your container to 100MB of memory.

```
docker run -m 100M busybox
```

However if your applications exceed their allocated memory they will be killed with an OOM exception. The problem you are having is likely because the applications you are running have a minimum requirement which is higher than your beaglebone black.

Grouping processes into one container will not help, they will still use the same amount of memory.

Comment: So containers itself doesn't take up memory? If I try to install everything bare-metal and run the same processes would it use the same amount of memory?
thank you for your awnser

Comment: Containers will not use extra memory. It is just another linux process running, it just runs in a different namespace.

Comment: Nice. Thank you!